# Knockout JS -> Update the view with value from new GET Call

Tags: api, jquery, post, knockout.js, get

I am consuming web services. I am making GET call to get all the questions -> user will answer that question and post it using the post call. This part is working as expected right now. Now, I would like make another GET call as soon as POST call is successful. I am able to make a GET call after POST call is complete but view is still showing data from my old GET call. How can I update the view with information from new GET call.

GET -> POST -> New GET (Data is not updated in this call.)

JSON

```
{
   "Respondent_ID":"hello111",
   "Group_Name":"",
   "Product_ID":80,
   "Language_ID":1,
   "First_Name":"hello",
   "Last_Name":"111",
   "Respondent_EMail":"",
   "Gender":"M",
   "AllQuestions":[
      {
         "Question_Number":76,
         "Question_Text":"I think ",
         "Definition":"",
         "Answer":0
      },
      {
         "Question_Number":77,
         "Question_Text":"I am ",
         "Definition":"",
         "Answer":0
      },
      {
         "Question_Number":78,
         "Question_Text":"I am mild mannered",
         "Definition":"",
         "Answer":0
      },
      {
         "Question_Number":79,
         "Question_Text":"I am strong",
         "Definition":"",
         "Answer":0
      },
      {
         "Question_Number":80,
         "Question_Text":"I am a risk taker",
         "Definition":"",
         "Answer":0
      }
   ],
   "AnswerChoice":[
      {
         "Answer_Choice":"Strongly disagree",
         "Answer_Choice_Value":1
      },
      {
         "Answer_Choice":"Disagree",
         "Answer_Choice_Value":2
      },
      {
         "Answer_Choice":"Neutral",
         "Answer_Choice_Value":3
      },
      {
         "Answer_Choice":"Agree",
         "Answer_Choice_Value":4
      },
      {
         "Answer_Choice":"Strongly agree",
         "Answer_Choice_Value":5
      }
   ]
}
```

--

```
 @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Questions";
    }

    <html>
    <body>       
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>             
    <script>       
       function GetAllEmployees() {              
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/Questions?respondent_id=hello111',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {                   
                    var data2 = data.AllQuestions;        
                    var viewModel = {
                        data: ko.mapping.fromJS(data2),
                        Question_Number: ko.observable(data.AllQuestions[0].Question_Number),
                        Question_Text: ko.observable(data.AllQuestions[0].Question_Text),                    

                        save: function () {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/api/lms',
                                type: 'POST',                      
                                data: data, 
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function (data) {                              
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: '/api/Questions?respondent_id=hello111',
                                        type: 'GET',
                                        dataType: 'json',
                                        success: function (data) {
                                            //How can update the view with the new data I got from the get call. 
                                            }

                                            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
                                        }
                                    });        

                                },
                                error: function (x, y, z) {
                                    alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
                                }
                            });
                        }       
                    }                       

                     ko.applyBindings(viewModel);     

                },
                error: function (x, y, z) {
                    alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
                }
            });
        }         

    </script>              

    </body>
    </html>       
            <a href="javascript:GetAllEmployees();"> Get Questions</a>       
            <form data-bind="submit: save">
    <table>
    <thead>
          <tr><th>#</th>Question<th>Strongly disagree</th><th>Strongly disagree</th><th>Disagree</th><th>Neutral</th><th>Agree</th><th>Strongly agree</th></tr>
               </thead>              
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: $data">
      <tr>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text: Question_Number"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text: Question_Text"></span>
            </td>

          <td><input type="radio" class="radio" value="1" data-bind="attr: { name: Question_Number}"></td>

           <td><input type="radio" class="radio" value="2" data-bind="attr: { name: Question_Number }"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" class="radio" value="3" data-bind="attr: { name: Question_Number }"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" class="radio" value="4" data-bind="attr: { name: Question_Number }"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" class="radio" value="5" data-bind="attr: { name: Question_Number }"></td>
                </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
         <button type="submit">Go</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Can you post your VM code?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by VM. When i say views, I just meant html code below. I just wanted to see how can I update the html with new GET call. how to update the bind might be better way of asking? I tried some of the options in knockout js site but nothing seems to be working. I know I dont have to do whole lot extra to update the value because thats what knock is made to do.

Comment: I have to go through your ViewModel Code and give me your response json for the request "/api/Questions?respondent_id=hello111"

Comment: oh ok, I have posted the sample json for the request "/api/Question?respondent_id=hello11" in my question now.

Answer (score 0):

You must un-nest your code.

And you should start to use jQuery's native `.get()` and `.post()` calls and deferred callbacks (`.then()`, `.done()`, `.fail()`, `.always()`) for Ajax handling.

I rewrote your JS code:

```
function showAjaxError(x, y, z) {
    alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
}
function QuestionViewModel(respondentId) {
    var self = this;

    self.data = ko.observableArray();
    self.currentQuestionId = ko.observable();
    self.currentQuestion = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.data()[self.currentQuestionId()];
    });

    self.mapQuestions = function (rawData) {
        return ko.mapping.fromJS(rawData.AllQuestions);
    };
    self.rewind = function () {
        self.currentQuestionId(0);
    };
    self.updateFromServer = function () {
        $.get('/api/Questions', { respondent_id: respondentId })
        .then(self.mapQuestions)
        .done(self.data)
        .done(self.rewind)
        .fail(showAjaxError);
    };
    self.save = function () {
        $.post('/api/lms', { data: ko.mapping.toJS(self.data) })
        .done(self.updateFromServer)
        .fail(showAjaxError);
    };

    self.updateFromServer();
}

ko.applyBindings(new QuestionViewModel('hello111'));
```

Notes

- `'/api/Questions?respondent_id=hello111'` should not be hard-coded. Make it a variable.
- View models work best when they are built with a constructor, because otherwise it's very hard to make them refer to themselves internally.
- Don't repeat yourself. Make small, re-usable functions (like `showAjaxError()`) and re-use them. If your code nests more than 3 levels deep you are doing it wrong.
- By commonly accepted coding style conventions, everything that is not a constructor starts with a lowercase letter and names don't have underscores (i.g. `questionText` instead of `Question_Text`).

Comment: Thank you for your response and some suggestions for coding. I am having problem posting the data that is part of save() method. I am trying to post the same data I got from get call with user responses on it. So, in json, I will add value to "Answer". Of course, I would like to check value before making post call. But, in your example how can I pass data from get call with user input and post it.

Comment: As I said, it's not clear to me what data you are trying to post. The entire model (`self.data`) maybe?

Comment: yup self.data. but data is slightly modified with user input. but structure is same as what I get from GET call. I hope i am making sense.

Comment: Since `self.data` contains a `ko.mapping.fromJS` I would think you will need to post the reverse (`ko.mapping.toJS(self.data)`) to the server.

Comment: @slamsal I've updated my answer once more. I think it's pretty close to what you want.

Comment: I gotta add beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("7609" + ":" + "XXXXXXXXXX")); } . Its basically a basic authentication to post anything. How would i add to $.post. I have done with $.ajax. Can I do it with $.post. It is probably not a good security practice. We are in prototype phase. I just want it to work as expected. We will probably use different authentication later.

Comment: You can configure [`$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { /* ... */} })`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) once then you would not have to set it again on your page.

Comment: Note that I've switched from your `Question_Number` and `Question_Text` observables to a `currentQuestion` computed observable. You might want to add `self.nextQuestion` and `self.prevQuestion` functions.

Comment: How would I trigger above javascript? Also, should i change " <span data-bind="text: Question_Number"></span>" to " <span data-bind="text: currentQuestionId"></span>" because Question_Number is switched to currentQuestionId.

Comment: I think you will find out the answers to these questions yourself. They are somewhere between "very obvious" and "not very hard" and finding out yourself will help you understand better.